# Override Control Template Property value in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, controltemplate

I have a `ListBoxItem` template like below

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="Padding"
                Value="20" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <Border x:Name="Bd"
                            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

In above sample `Padding` is 20 by default. So the `Border` control named **Bd** also gets the same value. So above resource will replace all the `ListboxIem` of `ListBox` in my window with the defined one. I have a specific `ListBox` which contains a `ToggleButton` also get the `Padding` value 20. My requirement is to make `Padding` value to 10 for this specific `ListBox` border. Could anyone please help me on this. Thanks in advance

```
<ListBox Name="lb">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}">
                <TextBlock x:Name="txt">
                        </TextBlock>
            </ToggleButton>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a new style for your listbox that will be based on the original style but overrides the `Padding` property. This way, the style you set explicitly for the listbox will be used instead of the one defined in the window's resources:

```
<Window>
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="listBoxItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="20" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                        <Border x:Name="Bd"
                                Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource listBoxItemStyle}">
    </Window.Resources>

    <ListBox Name="lb">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource listBoxItemStyle}">
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10" />
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="txt">
                    </TextBlock>
                </ToggleButton>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Window>
```